# Suggest an efficient way to query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Given a table `[a, b, c, d]`, I want to select exactly those rows which have `max(a)` within groups of `c`

i.e. rows with `a` = `select max(a) from table group by c`

What is the most efficient way to do this ? Can I use partition clause etc etc?

Answer (score 2):

In real world there exists almost anytime a clue, a particularity of problem, that can be speculated in your favor.

Your problem though is an ideal case, has no particularity. This query will full scan the table and then will make some sorts to find the maximum a:

```
select a,b,c,d
from(
    select 
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d, 
      row_number() over (partition by c order by a desc) as rnk_in_group_of_c
    from table
)
where rnk_in_group_of_c = 1;
```

This query is better than using a subquery to find the max because it may lead to more than one full scan, unwanted nested loops or other performance issues.

Note that if you want all rows that have tha maximum a(ie there are two equal maximum rows) you should use `dense_rank()` function instead of `row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `keep (dense_rank first` this helped me a lot and the performance can be a lot better.

```
select 
   max(a) a,
   max(b) keep (dense_rank first order by a desc) b,
   c,
   max(d) keep (dense_rank first order by a desc) d
from table
group by c
```

Comment: The performance is not necessarily best as [Rob van Wijk](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/keep-clause.html) explains very well but with a small number of columns it can be a lot quicker.

Comment: @Ben - As an amateur I've only done this once and it worked well, as could be seen from my past question. I appreciate your response as I'm learning! :)

Comment: We're all learning :-); or at least I hope so! Read the blog post; it is a very good example of why KEEP should be used; it's just not always quicker on large numbers of columns. If speed is not an issue but TEMP space is then it can still be worthwhile as you'll use less as the SORT GROUP BY reduces the number of rows that have to be calculated.

Comment: @Ben-Thank you for the [Blog](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/keep-clause.html). Just the discussion that's occuring here!

Answer (score 0):

Optional order by may be added after partition:

```
 SELECT max(a) OVER (PARTITION BY c) max_c FROM...
```